Where is the `javax.annotation.processing.Generated` class?
In my project, I have tried both Java 8 and Java 11 and both are failing to resolve javax.annotation.processing.Generated despite having this dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

Which dependency should I use for this class to be able to compile with both Java 8 and Java 11? Since I am using Datanucleus, I do not have direct control over which one to import.

It's in the standard library since version 9: javax.annotation.processing.Generated. Note if your code is modular and code is being generated into your module, then make sure your module-info descriptor includes a requires static java.compiler; directive. The static keyword here means the dependency is required at compile-time but optional at run-time.
